# SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 : Installing monitoring service

Tags: windows-services, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are setting up Tridion 2011 SP1 CDS  (.net based) on one of our servers.
We are sruck at point 'Installing Monitoring as a Wndows Service'.
Evern after running the batch file 'StartCDInstaller.bat' and following the procedure, we cannot locate the **Tridion Monitoring Agent** service in the windows services.
Are we missing something?

Also another question regarding CDS, can we change the location of config files (Deployer, Storage_conf etc) post Installation? Or do we need to re-run the installer?

Update:
The same error even after reinstalling the monitoring service.
"**The Event log details: The description for Event ID 100 from source TCDmonitor cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted**"

Answer (score 6):

You can change the location of tridion folder structure by setting the System variable in environment variable(Control panel -> system and security -> System -> Advance -> Environment variables -> system variables) called "Tridion_Home" and value as "d:\tridion" (this is the path of the tridion folder ). You can test this after going to run and type %tridion_home% .

Answer (score 6):

If for some reason the Tridion Monitoring Service was not installed by the installer, you can do it manually.

- Locate the file cd_monitor.exe (it is on the installation CD in Content Delivery\roles\monitoring\windows).
- Copy it to a location where you keep your executables (e.g. to the Tridion\bin folder)
- Start a command prompt as administrator and type 'cd_monitor -install'
- Go to the services console and start the monitoring service

Comment: Hi Quirijn, Many thanks, this worked. However not able to start the service. It gives popup as 'The service started and stopped, some services stop automatically if they are not in use.... "

The Event log details:
The description for Event ID 100 from source TCDmonitor cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

Comment: Can you check if the service is running as local system?

Comment: Yes, the Service is running currently as local system. Should it run as TridionApp user?

Comment: No, local system is correct, I was clutching at straws.. Any progress Huston?

Comment: Anyone who faced a similar issue?

Comment: Do you have a TRIDION_HOME environment variable pointing to the Tridion installation folder? This must be a folder that contains the subfolders config and lib. And do you have a cd_license.xml in the config?

Comment: Can you also make sure you copy all jars from 'Content Delivery\roles\monitoring\java\lib' and 'Content Delivery\roles\monitoring\java\third-party-lib' to '<TridionInstallationfolder>\lib'. Also, make sure you have cd_utils.dll next to the cd_monitor.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue too, it was an x64 Content Delivery server with x64 Java installed. Manually installed the monitoring service but refused to start with:

*The description for Event ID 100 from source TCDmonitor cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 
Could not load Java runtime libraries at 
the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table*

The monitoring service requires 32bit Java, as soon as that is installed it started with no problem.

Hope that helps.

Scott